# Visual Studio 2017/Windows 10 losing individual keyboard shortcus - and cannot recreate

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 with a wireless keyboard, connected to my Notebook. My keyboard lost the connection to the notebook and I could not reconnect, until a restart.

After that, Visual Studio lost my individually created keyboard shortcuts. Even after a reset of the keyboard settings and re-assigning my shortcuts, it does not work. The keyboard combination is being recognized (shift+alt+o) and is being shown in the settings after closing the configuration window with OK. It appears that even the entry in the main menu is dead.

<s>However, the original shortcut works.</s> Scary, isn't it?

Does anyone have a solution which is not re-installing Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

**Discovery 1**

Found a solution (admin rights required). See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/3278/go-to-symbolfiletype-shortcut-dont-work.html

Helps out, sometimes. Maybe some restarts of VS 2017 required.

However, still have problems with the window grid, like others are describing here as well. Visual Studio 2017 seems to be a complete mess.

**Discovery 2**

Consider this article, too: https://forums.asp.net/t/1103223.aspx?Find+also+find+and+replace+not+working+in+Visual+Studio

**Discovery 3**

Looks like that the problem had its origin really somewhere else. Someone plugged two cables from one monitor into my docking station. I use a notebook with docking station and two external monitors. One of the external monitors has been connected via DP and the other via DVI. This caused windows to think of one additional monitor in the setup (total count was 4), but with one deactivated.

As Windows 10 still cannot deal properly with multi monitor setups (think of DPI troubles on high res screens, especially when you mix a standard DPI monitor with a notebook that has a DPI screen), I currently have the suspicion, that Visual Studio opened the lost dialog windows on the non-existent screen.

Big oops. But maybe this article helps someone...